# Using two Events

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexbuilder, flex4.6

I have a little issue related to the events `MOUSE_MOVE` and `TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM`.

I want to distinguish both events, when I'm zooming an object `MOUSE_MOVE` should not act.

In the functions of both events, I start indicating `event.stopPropagation();` but no success, so if I press with one finger and move, the `MOUSE_MOVE` Event should work, but when I press with two fingers, `MOUSE_MOVE` should not work.

Is there any way that when i could prevent MOUSE_MOVE Event act when I'm Zooming the object?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. I'm not sure what order the events you are describing fire in, though, so even this may not work. `event.preventDefault()` may also help.

Docs for it are here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation%28%29

and here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#preventDefault%28%29

You should be able to check the `event.cancelable` Boolean property to see if the default behaviour can be prevented or not.

Comment: I was afraid of that. One last thought: does it make a difference if you add the event listeners in a different order, with `TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM` added first, and including all of `stopPropagation()`, `stopImmediatePropagation()`, and `preventDefault()` in that first listener?  (I'm asking rather than trying myself because I don't have a touchscreen available with which to test) If that doesn't work then you'll have to come up with another solution, such as delaying the mouse move for a few hundred milliseconds to see if a second finger touches down.

Comment: I will check it and comment you the results.